# Symfony3 Missing argument 2 for CommonBundle\Controller\{closure}()

Tags: symfony

I have an error and can't find where it's from:

```
->add('Webmaster',          ChoiceType::class, array(
        'required' => false,
        'choices' => $listWebmasters,
        'choice_label' => function($value, $key, $index)
        {
            return ($this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Compte')->find($value)->getNom().' '.$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Compte')->find($value)->getPrenom());
        },
        'choice_value' => function($value, $key, $index)//Line of the error
        {
            return ($this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Compte')->find($value)->getNom().' '.$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CommonBundle:Compte')->find($value)->getPrenom());

        }))
```

I tried without the 'choice_value' option and it works; I tried with a copy of the 'choice_label' and still not working. 'choice_value' is used as 'choice_label'. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-value

## EDIT

The exact error:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for
>   CommonBundle\Controller\DefaultController::CommonBundle\Controller{closure}()

Comment: Can you edit your post, and show what the exact error is?

Comment: Done. It's really the same as the title.

Comment: The error message seems to point to your controller code. Can you post more of it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove $key and $index from parameters. It helped me.

```
 'choice_value' => function($value)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: how did that help you?

Comment: it works if you're dealing with an EntityType::class